# No symbol tape information available - gdb 4.8 on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, gcc, gdb, fortran, fortran95

I'm trying to debug a Fortran 95 program using gdb 4.8. When I encounter a breakpoint (or the error I'm trying to debug), I cannot print any information on local variables using the `info` command. I also get a `No symbol tape information available` error when running `bt full`.

I don't believe this is related to the version of gdb as I first tried installing the version from Homebrew and got the same error. I then removed the Homebrew installation and compiled and installed the latest available version of gdb from source. My Fortran file is compiled with the `-g` flag and the `-fbacktrace` flag and has no explicit optimization flag, but I have attempted to compile with `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`, and `-O0`. All give the same error.

Possibly related is the fact that, upon running the code, I get loads of warnings. Here is a small excerpt:

```
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_c8_i4.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_c8_i8.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i16_i16.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i16_i4.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i16_i8.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i4_i16.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i4_i4.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i4_i8.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/gcc-4.9.2/build/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/libgfortran/.libs/pow_i8_i16.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

I have `gcc` installed by Homebrew but `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin`, so this is is probably the default Mac install. `/private/tmp/gcc-dmSW1S/` does not exist. Can provide any other information needed.

Comment: Are you really running gdb 4.8?  That version is positively ancient.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a sufficiently ancient version of `gdb` that it won't be able to read debug symbols from your objects compiled with gcc 4.9.  The 4.x version of GDB are at least 15 years old and and date back to the gcc 2.95 / egcs era of compilers.  Numerous ABI and debug symbol changes make gdb 4.x unsuitable for debugging objects compiled with GCC 4.9.

For objects compiled with GCC 4.9 and default debug symbol output (DWARF4 iirc), you'll want GDB 7.5.1 or newer.  The current GDB release is 7.9.

Comment: @laplacian13 This answer assumes you are actually using gdb 4.x, which is hard to believe.  If you are not, please update your question and I'll revise or remove this answer.